# Numpy subsetting/slicing not not returning expected value

Tags: python, numpy

Looking at the code below I do not understand why a=a[0] drops the first axis, reshapes the array and then assigns the new array to a. I would have thought that a=a[0] would have taken the first value of axis 0, if it exists, and assigned it to a.

I have tried looking through the numpy documentation but with no success. Apparently I am unable to even frame the problem properly.

-->Edit; Thanks for the response. I'll try to clarify my question.

I understand what a= a[0] is doing, empirically, I do not understand why. What are the rules governing this behavior?

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a=np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])
>>> a.shape
(10,)
>>> a=a.reshape(1,10,1)
>>> a.shape
(1, 10, 1)
>>> a=a[0]
>>> a.shape
(10, 1)
```

Comment: That's what it's doing. The first item in `a` is that (10,1)  shaped array.  You did not ask for the value in the flattened `a`, `a.ravel()[0]`.  Make an array like `a = np.arange(12).reshape(3,4)`, and practice indexing it in various ways.  The distinct values and shape will help you visualize the action.  Or make it bigger with shape (2,3,4).

Comment: As a list the reshaped `a ` looks like `[[[1],[2],...]]`.  `a[0]` strips off the first layer, [[1],[2]...]`  It is still a list of lists.

Answer (score 0):

It's like if you're looking at an mxn matrix A and you say, show me what's in the fourth row a = A[3] you're going to get a vector of length n in the 'a' variable since it's just a row. The dimension of length m is no longer relevant because you have chosen exactly which value along that dimension you are looking at.